# How to make calculated Field that is virtual (ftADT) for Clientdataset in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I want to make field "All.OrdAll" calculated or internal calculated that will sum Fields Ord.. on each input value. I make clientdataset (CDS) at runtime. To make changes on cds I must close it, but If I close it I lose access to the field that I need to make calculated. Note that it is virtual (ftADT).
Please, help with some code.

```
with cds do
begin
Close;
fieldDefs.Clear;
FieldDefs.Add('SN',ftInteger);
FieldDefs.Add('NAME',ftString,40);
FieldDefs.Add('ALL',ftADT,3);
FieldDefs.Add('OrdAll',ftFloat);
FieldDefs.Add('KolAll',ftFloat);
FieldDefs.Add('MinAll',ftFloat);

For i:=0 to High(Bases)
  do begin
    FieldDefs.Add(Bases[i].Name,ftADT,4);
    FieldDefs.Add('Price'+IntToStr(Bases[i].SN),ftFloat);
    FieldDefs.Add('ORD'+IntToStr(Bases[i].SN),ftFloat);
    FieldDefs.Add('Kol'+IntToStr(Bases[i].SN),ftFloat);
    FieldDefs.Add('MIN'+IntToStr(Bases[i].SN),ftFloat);
    end;
CreateDataSet;
end;
cds.close;
TADTField(cds.FieldByName('All')).Fields.FieldByName('OrdAll').
FieldKind:=fkInternalCalc;
cds.FieldDefs.Update;
cds.Open;
```

Comment: Is your `cds` supposed to contain a nested dataset?  What is `Bases` declared as?

Answer (score 0):

// (modified from original incorrect suggestion using FieldDefs.Add)

// Try using AddfieldDef, it returns a TFieldDef

```
var 
  fieldDef: TFieldDef; 

// 
fieldDef := FieldDefs.AddFieldDef; 
fieldDef.DataType := ftFloat; 
fieldDef.InternalCalcField := true; 
fieldDef.Name := 'OrdAll';
```

Comment: [dcc32 Error] RequestU.pas(356): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Comment: I added this: TADTField(cds.Fields[2]).Fields[0].FieldKind := fkInternalCalc; but get message: Argument out of range

Comment: Sorry, FieldDefs.Add does not return a value. I was confusing it with something else.
Try using AddfieldDef, it returns a TFieldDef
(this time I verified that it does compile)

var
  fieldDef: TFieldDef;

...
 fieldDef := FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
 fieldDef.DataType := ftFloat;
 fieldDef.InternalCalcField := true;
 fieldDef.Name := 'OrdAll';

Comment: As your answer is factually wrong, you should either delete it or correct it.